# Show result of js function in erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a js function which returns array

```
function getArray(){
     var array = [];

     $(".field").each(function() {
        array.push($(this).attr("id"));
     })    

     return array;
}
```

And I've got a button_tag

```
<%= button_tag "heh",:type => "button",  :onclick => "return getArray();"  %>
```

I need to get the result of `getArray()` function after clicking on button_tag and show it on the html page  or console.

Comment: The javascript runs after the `erb` has been rendered.  You need your javascript function to update the DOM.  With jQuery, you might do something like `$('button.my-button').html( array.join(", ") );` which would stick the array joined by commas in to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

To show it on console just use `console.log`, so replace :

```
return array;
```

By :

```
console.log(array);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= button_tag "heh",:type => "button",  :onclick => "console.log(getArray())"  %>
```

Note that if you need the string representation of the array, you'll have to call toString() method i.e. getArray().toString(). But for the purpose of console log alone, getArray() will do.